# C# как отправить несколько кук с одинаковым именем?

Tags: c#, cookie

Куки с одинаковым именем автоматически перезаписываются. Это даже в MSDN написано. Но вот сайт, с которым работаю, как-то умудряется в браузере 2 куки с одинаковым именем хранить и передавать. Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вверху то что возвращает сайт в ответ на GET запрос (в фидлере выделенная кука тоже 2 раза устанавливается), а внизу то что доходит до сервера в POST запросе, никаких обработок не производится, прямо так как в первом абзаце все и шлется, но к серверу только 1 кука доходит....

Скрин с POST запроса фидлера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как реализовать отправку 2 кук с одинаковыми именами в 1 запросе?

Comment: А что вернёт программа при вытаскивании куки по имени Ы?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, есть подозрение, что это куки на разные домены, или же, разные пути. Т.е. значение у них одно и то же, но вот остальные атрибуты - нет.

Вот тут (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name) этот вопрос еще обсуждался.

Comment: Да, пути разные. Но как их отправить вместе на сервер...